# Added more flour than what the recipe calls for to make butter cookies

Tags: cookies, recipe-scaling

In the process of baking some butter cookies using the following recipe, I mistakenly added 1/2 cup flour more than what the recipe calls for, and it is now mixed with other ingredients (in a food processor). This happened 3 days ago and I have the semi-batter in an airtight container on the counter since then. I'd like to know if there is any way to save the ingredients. I think I could double the recipe but not sure how it will turn out considering the 48+ hours that it lived in the kitchen.  Here's the recipe:

> 100gr butter
>
> 2/3 cup powdered sugar
>
> 1/8 tsp vanilla powder
>
> 3 egg yolks
>
> 2 cups flour

Comment: Why did you refrigerate it for three days?

Comment: Well, I did not! @Catija I left it on the counter because I wanted to make sure what I think must be done about it is actually the right thing to do... and *whispers* I wasn't in the mood for another baking mission!

Comment: If you left it on the **counter** for three days it is **definitely** unsafe to eat due to the egg yolks.

Answer (score 2):

If you added too much flour, you could increase the rest of the ingredients, so that the ratios are more or less equal than in the original recipe.

In your case, in theory, you have about 125% flour, so you would need 125 gram of butter, about 4/5 cup of powdered sugar,  3⁄20 of vanilla extract and 3.75 egg yolks.
However in practice, I think you would be fine if you would leave the other ingredients as is, or if the egg yolks are rather small, add a fourth one. A small increase of sugar would work though.

Nevertheless, as your batter was in the fridge for three days, I would throw it out because of the egg yolks.